# vuelidate vues js between rule not working exactly

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuelidate

I have to validate form with vue js before sening data, so I use vuelidate package, 
I have a quantity filed that it has min and max value, I used `betwwen`rule from `vuelidate` like this :

```
    validations : {
   quantity: {
        required,
        between : between(1, this.quantityMAx)
      },
    }
```

and `quantityMax is a computed attribute :

```
 quantityMax(){
    if(this.item){
      //console.log(parseFloat(this.item.qte_stock) - parseFloat(this.item.qte_stock_min))
      return parseFloat(this.item.qte_stock) - parseFloat(this.item.qte_stock_min)
  
    }
      else return 1
    },
```

and I got the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties
    ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./resources/assets/js/views/damage/Create.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& Create.vue:288
    ....
```

But I used this validation in a componenet and it's working, I d'ont know what is the error ! 
I imort rules like this :

```
const {
  required,
  minValue,
  between,
  maxLength,
  maxValue,
}
 = require('vuelidate/lib/validators')
```

and just between that it has the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by using

```
validations () {
return { ...}
}
```

and not `validions : { ....}`